# Calculation steps in Haskell foldr

Tags: haskell, fold

Does anybody know the steps of haskell 'foldr' use of function?

#### GHCI Command Window:

```
foldr (\x y -> 2*x + y) 4 [5,6,7]
```

#### The result after evaluation:

```
40
```

#### Steps on this,

```
Prelude> foldr (\x y -> 2*x + y) 4 [5,6,7] 
6 * 2 + (7 * 2 + 4)
12 + 18 = 30
5 * 2 + 30 = 40 v
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One definition of foldr is:

```
foldr            :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f acc []     = acc
foldr f acc (x:xs) = f x (foldr f acc xs)
```

The [wikibook on Haskell](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/List_processing) has a nice graph on foldr (and on other folds, too):

```
  :                         f
 / \                       / \
a   :       foldr f acc   a   f
   / \    ------------->     / \
  b   :                     b   f
     / \                       / \
    c  []                     c   acc
```

I.e. `a : b : c : []` (which is just `[a, b, c]`) becomes `f a (f b (f c acc))` (again, taken from wikibook).

So your example is evaluated as `let f = (\x y -> 2*x + y) in f 5 (f 6 (f 7 4))` (let-binding only for brevity).

Comment: This is Great!! Thanks for help! Now I fully understand steps for foldr.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually easily visualize it for yourself:

```
import Text.Printf

showOp f = f (printf "(%s op %s)") "0" ["1","2","3"]
```

then

```
Main> showOp foldr
"(1 op (2 op (3 op 0)))"
Main> showOp foldl
"(((0 op 1) op 2) op 3)"
Main> showOp scanl
["0","(0 op 1)","((0 op 1) op 2)","(((0 op 1) op 2) op 3)"]
```

Answer (score 0):

[This was supposed to be a comment on delnan's remark, but was too wordy...]

Yoon, you can open a private 'conversation' with `lambdabot` on the #haskell irc (e.g. at http://webchat.freenode.net/ ).  She has a simple reflection ability, so you can type meaningless letters, e.g.

```
    Yoon: > foldr (\x y -> 2*x + y) o [a,b,c,d]
lamdabot: 2 * a + (2 * b + (2 * c + (2 * d + o)))
```

This says what is evaluated, but as Edka points out you get a picture of the order of evaluation from say

```
     Yoon: > reverse (scanr (\x y -> 2*x + y) o [a,b,c,d])
lambdabot: [o,2 * d + o,2 * c + (2 * d + o),2 * b + (2 * c + (2 * d + o)),2 * a + (2 * b + (2 * c + (2 * d + o)))
```

I remember imprinting some good lessons playing around with `foldr`, `foldl`, `scanr`, `scanl` and this clever device.